# Conditional composite key in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements, composite-key

So I have this table with a composite key, basically 'userID'-'data' must be unique (see my other question [SQL table - semi-unique row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026379/sql-table-semi-unique-row))

However, I was wondering if it was possible to make this only come into effect when userID is not zero? By that I mean, 'userID'-'data' must be unique for non-zero userIDs?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks
Mala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL constraints apply to every row in the table.  You can't make them conditional based on certain data values.

However, if you could use `NULL` instead of zero, you can get around the unique constraint.  A unique constraint allows multiple entries that have `NULL`.  The reason is that uniqueness means no two *equal values* can exist.  Equality means `value1 = value2` must be true.  But in SQL, `NULL = NULL` is *unknown*, not true.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, userid INT, data VARCHAR(64));

INSERT INTO MyTable (userid, data) VALUES (   1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO MyTable (userid, data) VALUES (   1, 'bar');
INSERT INTO MyTable (userid, data) VALUES (NULL, 'baz');
```

So far so good, now you might think the following statements would violate the unique constraint, but they don't:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (userid, data) VALUES (   1, 'baz');
INSERT INTO MyTable (userid, data) VALUES (NULL, 'foo');
INSERT INTO MyTable (userid, data) VALUES (NULL, 'baz');
INSERT INTO MyTable (userid, data) VALUES (NULL, 'baz');
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! As i said i used a different solution, but you gave me a perfect answer to my question and I will doubtless use it in the future =)